# RegEx replacement between "arbitrary" delimiters

Tags: c#, .net, regex, delimiter, replace

I am having a bit of an issue regarding replacing parts of a text file between "arbitrary" delimiters.

Here is what I want to do: I have mark-up like the following:

```
//   [ADX START] ANYTHING //   [ADX END] 

<!--    [ADX START] --> ANYTHING <!-- [ADX END]  -->

/*   
 [ADX START] */  ANYTHING /*  [ADX END]        */
```

So, these are different commenting styles and I want to grab the opening [ADX START] (including the surrounding comment), then the text in between and finally, the final [ADX END].

Hence, I give it a text file like this:

```
test.php:
<?php
BEFORE    
// [ADX START]
REMOVEME
// [ADX END]
AFTER

test.css:
BEFORE    
/* [ADX START]*/
REMOVEME
/*[ADX END] */
AFTER
```

Becomes:

```
test.php:
<?php
BEFORE    
AFTER

test.css:
BEFORE    
AFTER
```

And so on. As you can see, there can be any number of whitespaces (or none) between the commenting-style and the delimiters.

So, what I came-up with so far is the following:

```
string newFileContent = Regex.Matches(fileContent, "(\\[ADX START\\].*\\[ADX END\\])", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

However, that doesn't do anything. I think what trips me up is the brackets etc.; furthermore, I would like to simply be able to drop-in different commenting styles such as #, //, /**/, etc;

Any pointer in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to use a more uniform commenting syntax for the delimiters?

Comment: Hello Asad, thank you for your comment. I am not entirely sure what you mean. However, all I need is a Regex that allows me to "drop-in" two arbitrary delimiters which then goes out and replaces everything between those (including the delimiters themselves).

Comment: With this kind of irregular input, I don't believe Regex is your best option. Write your own parser for this.

Comment: I thought about that since it's not too hard to do this with a parser. However, the parser won't be able to disregard the amount of whitespace between the delimiter and the comment. So I would have to account for "// DELIMITER" and "// (more whitespace) DELIMITER" and "//  (even more whitespace)  DELIMITER" etc.; To the power of the number of possibilities with the closing delimiter (not to mention possible linebreaks). Or I enforce that it *has* to be one space between comment and delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use singline option and regex like this

```
string strRegex =@"(\/\/|\/\*).*?\[ADX START\].*?\[ADX END\]\s*(\*\/)?";
                         ^                      ^                 ^
                         |                      |                 |->match */ 0 or 1 time
                         |                      |
                         |                      |->match lazily till the first ADX END
                         |->match // or /*
string s=Regex.Replace(fileContent,strRegex,"",RegexOptions.Singleline);//replace it
```

Comment: Hi Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It,

Thank you so much for the excellent explanation as well as the Regex! I am beginning to understand how it works, however, when using this Regex, the outputString is identical to the inputString. I also love the way it incorporates two commenting styles so I will be able to replicate the "OR" operator for more styles. Would you know, by any chance, why it is not working? My input is as follows: 

            string contentBefore = @"
<?php
before
// [ADX START]
I will be replaced


sdf
sdf
// [ADX END]
after
";

Comment: Oh my god, this is absolutely awesome Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It! Thank you so much. I now understand the final "match 0 or 1". However, somehow it does not match the final one. For example, INPUT: "\r\n<?php\r\nbefore\r\n// [ADX START]\r\nI will be replaced\r\n\r\n\r\nsdf\r\nsdf\r\n// [ADX END]\r\nafter\r\n\r\n\r\n/*[ADX START]*/\r\nreplaced AGAIN\r\n/* [ADX END] */\r\n\r\nFinal after\r\n" | OUTPUT: "\r\n<?php\r\nbefore\r\n\r\nafter\r\n\r\n\r\n */\r\n\r\nFinal after\r\n". The final "*/" is still there, unfortunately.

Comment: You're a freakin' superstar, mate! Works perfectly and I was even able to add another commenting style: <!-- --> as follows:  "(\/\/|\/\*|<!--).*?\[ADX START\].*?\[ADX END\]\s*(\*\/|-->)?" ... Thank you very much again! :-)

Comment: @TEST regex is quite simple mate.;)

Answer (score 0):

`.*` won't normally match across newlines; you need `RegexOptions.Singleline` to make it do that. However, then you should use `.*?` to get a non-greedy match. Also, your regex does nothing to try to capture the part of the line before `[ADX START]` or after `[ADX END]`. Finally, you're using `Regex.Matches`, not `Regex.Replace`, so it doesn't actually modify anything.

Try this:

```
Regex commentRegex = new Regex(@"^.*?\[ADX START\].*?\[ADX END\].?$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
string newFileContent = commentRegex.Replace(fileContent);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Barmar, I am just starting out with Regex and, hence, am having a few problems still. I just tried your Regex and a runtime-error is telling me there aren't enough brackets. I tried to place it before the final ".?$" but it did not yield the desired result - anyway thank you very much for the Regex, I will pick-it apart and try to understand it.

Comment: The `(` near the beginning is not needed, I just got rid of it. Try now. Note: I'm not a C# programmer, I might have gotten some details of that syntax wrong.

Comment: @Barmar use \ instead of \\ if you are using verbatim string i.e `@""`